# Img + some hidden Text, after hovering on it, img should turn bigger and text should turn visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hover

I tried with `css` and `javascript`, its kind of working but not very good. As soon as the text which is located directly in front of the `img` turns visible the image doesn't get the hover anymore and stays small... and it starts flickering.

Do you have an idea what I could do?

```js
displayDotTextonHover =  function displayDotTextonHover() {
    const purpleDot = document.querySelector(".bucketList img");

 purpleDot.addEventListener("mouseover", function (){
        document.querySelector(".bucketList img").style.transform= "scale(1.5)";
        document.getElementById("myBucketList").style.visibility="visible";
    });

   purpleDot.addEventListener("mouseout", function (){
        document.querySelector(".bucketList img").style.transform= "scale(1)";
        document.getElementById("myBucketList").style.visibility="hidden";
    });
};
```

```css
/*
.menu img:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

/*.menu img:hover~#myBucketList{
    visibility: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
}*/
```

```html
<div class = "bucketList">
  <img src="../images/Footer/blueDot.png"/>                  
  <p id="myBucketList">Bucket</br>List</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it without javascript.

**UPDATE on comment**

> if the text is on top of the Image

make your image container fit content, for example with `display: inline-block;` and do your modifications not on image hover, but on the container hover.

Look the snippet.

```css
.bucketList {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bucketList:hover .image {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5) translate(10%, 0);
}

.bucketList * {
  position: absolute;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#myBucketList {
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 30px;
  left: 70px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.bucketList:hover #myBucketList {
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bucketList">
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/business-stamp-illustration-sample-vector-id932071254" class="image" />
  <p id="myBucketList">Bucket List</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but does it still work for you if the text is on top of the Image? 
thats the problem Iam facing. The the hover effect of the image stops...